# SQL Join on partial column data (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Both columns are `tinyint` if it matters.

**Table1**

```
Version
--------
111115
222226
333337
```

**Table2**

```
ID  Year
--------
5   2015
6   2016
7   2017
```

I need to join on the ID from table 2 if it equals the last value in the version field from table 1.

Version 111115 would join to ID 5. I know how to select on things like this but is joining feasible? The result being:

```
111115  5  2015
```

TIA!

Comment: you can join on any modifications you make to a field, but there are performance hits.  So you could join on SUBSTRING(table1.Version, len(version)-1, 1) = Table2.ID  if you wanted to.  Odds are it would be slow.  Better bet is to throw this into a temp table, by selecting the substring and version into it, then joining that onto Table2

Comment: Will you ever have values of TABLE2.ID that are greater than 9? None of the answers so far address that situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RIGHT()` function to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B on RIGHT(A.Version,1) = B.ID
```

I would probably avoid having to do this very much though.  It is a faulty database design.  Perhaps add a column `ID` to table 1, and use:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ID = RIGHT(Version,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they are both integer, you can try the modulus operator. It takes the remainder after division. So `111115 % 10` is 5.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Version % 10 = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tblTest as table
(
    id INT,
    yearName INT
)


Declare @tblVersion as table
(
    VersionNo INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest values(5,2015)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values(6,2016)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values(7,2017)

INSERT INTO @tblVersion values(111115)
INSERT INTO @tblVersion values(111116)
INSERT INTO @tblVersion values(111117)


select 
*,RIGHT(VersionNo,1) 
from @tblVersion

SELECT 
*
FROM @tblTest T1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT RIGHT(VersionNo,1) AS VersionId,VersionNo FROM @tblVersion) T2 ON T2.VersionId=T1.id
```